# Form-control Css on Ajaxtoolkit not working

Tags: css, asp.net, combobox, connection-string

HI I have the following code

```
<tr class="data-contact-person">                       
    <td >
          <div class="input-group date" id="DateofPurchase"><input type="text" name="date-name" class=" form-control  date-name" />
               <span class="input-group-addon">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
               </span></div></td>

    <td><ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="Merchant" CssClass="form-control" name="Merchant-name" runat="server" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Merchant" DataValueField="Merchant" MaxLength="0" style="display:inline-block" ></ajaxToolkit:ComboBox>

               <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:QuenchConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Merchant] FROM [tblVendors]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </td>



    <td>  
           <select name="method-name" class="form-control method-name">
                 <option value= "Cash" >Cash</option>
                 <option value= "DebitCard" >Debit Card</option>
                 <option value= "DirectDebit" >Direct Debit</option>
                 <option value= "Cheque" >Cheque</option>
           </select>
    </td>
```

However the combo box doesn't match the style of the text boxes
[As seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO9Fw.png)

How do I get the **ComboBox** to look like the **DropdownBox** in the next column

Thanks

Comment: fix the css of the control - see how is rendered and fix it

Comment: Sorry I dont understand, The css works fine on the dropdown box in the next column but for some reason it looks like i have a textbox behind the combobox when i am using the same css

Comment: what is the rendered html page on that part ?

Comment: sorry, i am new to this. I have a table with various columns. I have one dropdown option that uses bootstrap css "form-control and looks ok. I have a second dropdown that i use the same Css on but it is not the same and the only difference is that I am using a combobox from the ajaxtoolkit